# Playing a cultist

Tags: call-of-cthulhu, trail-of-cthulhu

Is there any commercial setting or scenario to play a cultist in a Cthulhu related game, like Call of Cthulhu or Trail of Cthulhu? Playing the bad guys is a theme that usually come up sometime in most of the games...

Comment: That's not a "shopping" question at all. It's a question about thematics in RPGs.